# content appended with :after on text element with full width is relative to the text and not the element itself

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown from scratch

I want to add an arrow at the end of the container, but it keeps getting confined to be next to the text instead. If the span is a block element with a width of 100% and using :after for the arrow, why is it next to the text and not near the end of the element?

```
    <div id="wrap" style="border: solid 1px green; width: 100%;">
         <span style="border: solid 1px blue; width: 100%; display: block;">z</span>
    </div>

    span:after {
         display: inline-block;
         content: " ";
         width: 0;
         height: 0;
         border-left: 5px solid transparent;
         border-right: 5px solid transparent;
         border-top: 5px solid #aaaaaa;
         padding-top: 2px;
         position: relative;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/my272eze/

if I did it on the container instead (#wrap) the arrow appears on a new line.

http://jsfiddle.net/my272eze/3/

how would I get it within the container?

Comment: Because `:after` appends the pseudo element _inside_ the `span` not actually _after_ the span.

Comment: Because you haven't positioned it to the parent element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add

```
float: right;
margin: 6px;
```

to the the pseudo element

The [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dyaa/my272eze/5/)

Comment: @archytect so please mark it as solved so we can help other People

Answer (score 1):

`position: absolute` to the span tag and `position relative` to the span:after. Then move the arrow with left: x amount of pixels. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/my272eze/4/)**

```
span{

    position: absolute;

}

span:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: " ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work, at least not in Chrome on OSX. rather not guess the number of pixels either. dyaa's solution is simple